# Is it possible to embed a chromium browser within a blazor SPA

Tags: chromium, blazor

For a specific use case I am looking to run a chromium browser from within a Blazor single page application (iFrames are not a viable option as I need to listen to chromium-driven events).

The .NET implementations of chromium that I am aware of (EO.WebBrowser, CEFSharp) have WPF and Winforms implementation, but (understandably) not equivalent Blazor controls. Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: I think you are looking this https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-on-desktop-webwindow-experiment/. Currently, this feature completely experiment mode

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I am looking for. My Blazor application will be accessible over the web through a browser. Within the Blazor single page application, I need to be able to show an embedded third party website within a part of the page i.e. as you would typically using an iframe. However, instead of an iframe, I want to embed a chromium browser within my page so that my application can control what is displayed in the embedded browser, and listen to various events.

Comment: @AndrewHone did you ever get this working? is it possible to do it?